TP-Link Archer T4U limited to USB 2 speed
Archer T4u supports USB 3 according to official documentation but when I connect it to a USB 3 Port it is detected as a USB 2 device (as per lsusb output). I tried this on both my Ubuntu PC and laptop running Fedora 40 which both have newer USB 3.1 ports. The device works without installing any driver.

The performance of the device is dependent on the chip it uses which in turn determines which drive is used. So could you append to your question the result of the following command line 'lshw -c network' Then take a look at the following site to match the driver to the USB interface. The inference being if you are using the wrong but compatible drive it may well connect USB2 through a USB3 interface.https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/USB_WiFi_Chipsets.md  'lsusb' may well tell you the correct drive to use.

Added detailed output from lsusb to my proposed answer.

Fixed by installing the driver from: https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702
During the installation the script allows editing driver options.
Setting rtw_switch_usb_mode=1 in /etc/modprobe.d/88x2bu.conf allows the device to connect in USB 3 mode.
Output of lsusb -t:
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 003, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 004: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 004: Dev 004, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 004: Dev 004, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 004: Dev 004, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 005: Dev 005, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 005: Dev 005, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 005: Dev 005, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 480M
        |__ Port 006: Dev 006, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 003.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 004.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 005.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 12M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 003, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 003, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 003, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=[none], 12M
/:  Bus 006.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 007.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 008.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 009.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 002: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 010.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    |__ Port 002: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl88x2bu, 5000M

Here is the detailed output of lsusb for the device:
sudo lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/010/004
Device: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link Archer T4U ver.3
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            0 [unknown]
  bDeviceSubClass         0 [unknown]
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x2357 TP-Link
  idProduct          0x0115 Archer T4U ver.3
  bcdDevice            3.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11ac NIC
  iSerial                 3 123456
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0053
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              504mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           5
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 802.11ac NIC
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               3
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         287 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)



In case anyone is interested, I use this driver for my Archer T3U (same chipset) but it does not work when I enable that USB 3 setting.  The notes do say that USB 3 may not work for everyone and I guess that's why they block it by default.
